# Finding the k-longest sequences in an one-dimensional array?

Tags: php, algorithm, math, sequence, n-dimensional

In context of the realization of a project I need to find the k-longest sequences in PHP. There are many ways to implement this - but which algorithm is the fastest for PHP?

Which algorithm would you implement? (overview)

Which one is most-efficient and dynamic (numbers, strings, etc)? (fast?, time for n-elems?)

How would you implement it? (example)

Thank you!

---

***Post Scriptum***

I'm about to implement the ONISI k-nearest neightbour algorithm. The longest sequences are visualised in this schematic.
[image: The interaction history since t and the immediate history.]
This shematic gives a brief overview on the ONISI algorithm.[image]

The total/immediate-history-elements are strings representing a $state --> $action pattern.
This means, considering the first 3 elements of schematic (1), data would be displayed, for instance, like: `$immediate_history = array( array( "s2" => "a2" ), array( "s3" => "a3" ), array( "s1" => "a1" ) [..] );`

Still any questions about the problematic?

Cheers!

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Also, you can't represent the whole of schematic (1) with a PHP array in the way you've presented it, because PHP array keys have to be unique.  Doing it as a sequence of sub-arrays would be one alternative, eg: `array( array("s2" => "a2"), array("s3" => "a3"), array("s1" => "a1"),...)`

Comment: The representation is not as important as the algorithm for the analysis of the array for finding the k-longest sequence, of course, it might be represented like that - but nearly every representation can be implemented into a standardized algorithm. I changed my example after your alternative.

I already have been experimenting wit Tries, but it seemed inadequate for the actual case.

Comment: Try this one: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: My (personal) advice is: if you are really worried about performance, don't implement it in PHP, use an external function in a compiled language (C/C++ for instance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which algorithm would you implement?
> (overview)

KNN is a special case of a [variable-bandwidth, kernel density "balloon" estimator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_kernel_density_estimation) with a uniform kernel

> Which one is most-efficient and dynamic (numbers, strings, etc)? (fast?, time for n-elems?)

I depends on your data structure. An array is defnetly slower. But use of better and advanced structure will speed things up.

> How would you implement it? (example)

I highly doubt anyone will give you this here as the program is not a small one. You have to do this on your own.